# Retrieving all the rows with number 1

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

Probably really simple but I am trying to retrieve all the rows that contain the number 1. I tried grep without success and it seems I am really dumb using regular expressions.

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
t = data.frame(C1 = c(1,2,23,26,45), C2 = c("Plate1","Plate1","Plate2","Plate2","Plate4"), C3 = c("A1","A2","B10","C11","D1"), C4 = c(3,6,7,1,2))

t

  C1     C2  C3 C4
1  1 Plate1  A1  3
2  2 Plate1  A2  6
3 23 Plate2 B10  7
4 26 Plate2 C11  1
5 45 Plate4  D1  2
```

I would like to retrieve the rows where C3 contains 1, but not 10 or 11 which means row 1 and 5 with A1 and D1.

So the end result would be:

```
  C1     C2  C3 C4
1  1 Plate1  A1  3
5 45 Plate4  D1  2
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep`.  Match the pattern of one or more alphabets (upper case `[A-Z]+`) from the start of the string (`^`) followed by number 1 at the end (`$`) of the string in column 'C3' and use that to subset the rows.

```
t[grep("^[A-Z]+1$", t$C3),]
#  C1     C2 C3 C4
#1  1 Plate1 A1  3
#5 45 Plate4 D1  2
```

Comment: Of course it worked... a small explanation on the regular expression? It seems I was missing the $. What is this doing?